# Navigation title not showing on the center after pushing view controller onto NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with the root controller as a `UICollectionViewController` called `HomeController` which I have set up in my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))    
        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

Now in my HomeController I am trying to set the center text of a new `ViewController` (`dummySettingViewController`) I push onto the NavigationController as shown below:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    ...
    func showControllerForSettings(setting: SettingModel) {
        let dummySettingViewController = UIViewController()
        dummySettingViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.pushViewController(dummySettingViewController, animated: true)
        //THIS DOESN'T SET THE dummySettingViewController TITLE TEXT
        self.navigationItem.title = "TEST_TITLE"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is in this line `self.navigationItem.title = "TEST_TITLE"`. It doesn't set the center title text of the new `dummySettingViewController` that is pushed onto the `navigationController` but instead sets the `back button` text in the `NavBar` of the `dummySettingViewController` to `TEST_TITLE`.

In this line: `self.navigationItem.title = "TEST_TITLE"` when I use `self` is that referring to the `HomeViewController` navigationItem or the `NavBar` of the `navigationController`? I am confused on how the `NavBar` on each `ViewController` works? Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is in this line self.navigationItem.title = "TEST_TITLE". It doesn't set the center title text of the new dummySettingViewController that is pushed onto the navigationController but instead sets the back button text in the NavBar of the dummySettingViewController to TEST_TITLE.

That is exactly what it's expected to do. When you push a view controller onto a navigation controller, that view controller's navigation item is pushed onto the navigation bar. The *previous* view controller's navigation item title is then used as the title for the *current* view controller's back button, which is what you observed. You need to set "TEST_TITLE" on the `dummySettingViewController`'s navigation item, not on `self`'s (i.e. the previous view controller's) item.

Comment: Ohhhh so by default when I push `dummySettingViewController` into the `navigationController`, the navigation bar of the previous controller will be pushed onto the navigation bar of the `dummySettingViewController`? And this worked: `dummySettingViewController.navigationItem.title = "TEST_TITLE"`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not quite. Each `UINavigationController` instance has a *single* `UINavigationBar` instance. That navigation bar instance sets its title and any left or right buttons with values from the *topmost* (i.e. most recently pushed) `UINavigationItem` on its stack, and uses the navigation item one level deeper to set the back button text.

Comment: So does the `NavigationItem` of a `ViewController` represent the `NavBar` of that `ViewController`? I am a little bit confused on what the `NavigationItem` represents. Also does each view controller that gets pushed onto the `UINavigationController` shared that single `UINavigationBar` instance?

Comment: A `UINavigationItem` represents the *configuration* of the items in a navigation bar. That's why you have to add `UIBarButtonItem`s to a navigation item, instead of regular `UIView`s. The nav bar uses the item's configuration to create and set the views; you have no direct control over them. And yes, *all* view controllers that are pushed onto a single navigation controller share an instance of the navigation bar.